# CAShapeLayer rendering issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

I'm trying to create circle animation by adding `CAShapeLayer`s with different stroke colors:

```
    UIView *view = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self addCircleAnimationTo:view direction:YES];

- (void)addCircleAnimationTo:(UIView *)view direction:(BOOL)direction {
    CGFloat animationTime = 3;

    // Set up the shape of the circle
    int radius = view.frame.size.width/2;
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    // Make a circular shape
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                             cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

    // Center the shape in view
    circle.position = CGPointMake(radius,
                                  radius);

    circle.bounds = view.bounds;
    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    // switch color
    circle.strokeColor = (direction) ? [UIColor blueColor].CGColor : [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 5;
    circle.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
    circle.strokeStart = .0;
    circle.strokeEnd = 1.;

    // Configure animation
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = animationTime;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1;

    // Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.];

    // Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    // Add to parent layer
    [view.layer addSublayer:circle];
    // Add the animation to the circle
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)((animationTime-0.1) * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self addCircleAnimationTo:view direction:!direction];
    });
}
```

[image]

I'm wondering why I can see blue when white layer animates and how to get rid of this weird blue color border:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The antialiasing is what's causing the problem

When the white `CAShapeLayer` gets drawn over the blue, the edge gets blended with the previous edge blending that the antialiasing created.

**The only real solution is to clear the blue from underneath the white as you animate.** You can do this by animating the `strokeStart` property of the previous layer from `0.0` to `1.0`. You should be able to re-use your `drawAnimation` for this, by just changing the `keyPath`. For example, change your `dispatch_after` to:

```
- (void)addCircleAnimationTo:(UIView *)view direction:(BOOL)direction {

    // Insert your previous animation code, where drawAnimation is defined and added to the circle layer.    


    drawAnimation.keyPath = @"strokeStart"; // Re-use the draw animation object, setting it to animate strokeStart now.

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)((animationTime-0.1) * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self addCircleAnimationTo:view direction:!direction];
        [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"(un)drawCircleAnimation"]; // Sets the previous layer to animate out
    });

}
```

That way the antialiasing edge blending gets cleared from the blue layer, allowing the white layer to get a nice & clean antialiasing. **Just don't forget to remove the layer once you've animated it out!**

Another potential solution is to increase the stroke width of the white layer, so it strokes over the blue layer's edge blending, however I would imagine it would create an undesired effect. You could also disable antialiasing, but that would look horrible on the circle.

Comment: thanks, do you have also suggestion how to clear prev.layer color while animating?

Comment: yes, I would recommend animating the `strokeStart` property of the previous layer from `0.0` to `1.0` as you animate the next layer. I have updated my answer

Comment: I have added a sleeker example that integrates into your current animation method.

Comment: seems like works fine, the only thing left is to remove previous layer and when I do this after unDrawAnimation - it's flickering for a moment

Comment: so actually I have to remove it before unDrawAnimation stops, do u know how to avoid it?

Comment: make sure you're actually removing it after it has finished, I noticed your `dispatch_after` gets fired before the animation is completed

Comment: I guess better to use animation delegate, I'll try thanks

Answer (score 2):

You know that you are adding more and more shape layers after each call to `addCircleAnimationTo` ?

While you animate the new layer the old shape layer reminds below the new one. That is why you see it.

**[EDIT 2] SHORT EXPLANATION**

We create two layers first with blue path colour, second with white path colour.

To first layer we add **fill** animation - change of `layer.strokeEnd` property, we animate it from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 1. Half of duration from 0 to 1 and half of duration from 1 to 1 (visually nothing happens, but is needed).

We add **clear** animation - change of `layer.strokeStart`, we animate it from 0 to 1. Duration of this animation is half of duration of **fill** animation. Begin time is also half of **fill** animation because we want to move beginning of stroke when end stroke is still.

We add the same animations to second, white layer but with appropriate begin time offset, thanks to that white path unwinds and blue path winds.

**[EDIT] ADDED REAL ANSWER**

Here is my suggestion to solve your animation problem. Hope it helps ... :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.circle1 = [self circle:view.bounds];
    self.circle1.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.circle2 = [self circle:view.bounds];
    self.circle2.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    [view.layer addSublayer:self.circle1];
    [view.layer addSublayer:self.circle2];

    [self.circle1 addAnimation:[self fillClearAnimation:0] forKey:@"fillclear"];
    [self.circle2 addAnimation:[self fillClearAnimation:3] forKey:@"fillclear"];
}

- (CAAnimationGroup *)fillClearAnimation:(CFTimeInterval)offset
{
    CGFloat animationTime = 3;

    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *fill = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    fill.values = @[ @0,@1,@1];
    fill.duration = 2*animationTime;
    fill.beginTime = 0.f;
    CAKeyframeAnimation *clear = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeStart"];
    clear.values = @[ @0, @1];
    clear.beginTime = animationTime;
    clear.duration = animationTime;

    group.animations = @[ fill, clear ];
    group.duration = 2*animationTime;
    group.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + offset;

    group.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;

    return group;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)circle:(CGRect)frame
{
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    CGFloat radius = ceil(frame.size.width/2);

    // Make a circular shape
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                             cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

    // Center the shape in view
    circle.position = CGPointMake(radius,
                                  radius);

    circle.frame = frame;
    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    circle.lineWidth = 5;
    circle.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
    circle.strokeStart = 0.f;
    circle.strokeEnd = 0.f;

    return circle;
}
```

Comment: I knew it thanks, I'll care later about cleaning up stuff. 
>>While you animate the new layer the old shape layer reminds below the new one.That is why you see it. <<
actually new one should cover previous, this is what I expected

Comment: oh haha, completely missed that.. weird